# Installing My Qt app on the Symbian test device

Tags: c++, qt

after I have finished my code , it run perfectly. i want to try it on a Symbian Device ...

I connected My phone via usb and then i choose Sync and connect
I am using Qt Creator so i checked for Symbian device down left of the window.... and i run

I got the following error:

```
No device is connected. Please connect a device and try again.
Error while building project Project (target: Symbian Device)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nokia PC suite or nokia ovi suite to connect your mobile with PC.......It will automatically detect your device.